# Is there a way to select a range of elements in a named vector in R?

Tags: r

Is there a way to select a range, as opposed to specific, elements from a named vector in R?

```
vec<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
names(vec)<-c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May')

vec['Jan']
#Something along these lines?
vec['Jan':'Feb']
```

Comment: Not in base R, unfortunately. This is largely because `names` don't have to be unique, and this could only work with unique names. Some `tidyverse` functions let you specify columns of data frames this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

unlist(data.frame(t(vec)) %>% select(Jan:April), use.names = TRUE)

# Jan   Feb   Mar April 
# 1     2     3     4
```

Comment: I sort of like this the best.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match` from `base R` with `:` to get the sequence of index from the start and end based on the `names` of the vector and subset the `vec`

```
vec[match('Jan', names(vec)):match("April", names(vec))]
#   Jan   Feb   Mar April 
#   1     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
#Option 1
vec[names(vec) %in% c('Jan','Feb')]
```

Output:

```
Jan Feb 
  1   2
```

Or this:

```
#Index
initial <- 'Jan'
last <- 'Feb'
i1 <- which(names(vec)==initial)
i2 <- which(names(vec)==last)
#Option 2
vec[i1:i2]
```

Output:

```
Jan Feb 
  1   2
```

And some test:

```
#Test
initial <- 'Jan'
last <- 'April'
i1 <- which(names(vec)==initial)
i2 <- which(names(vec)==last)
#Option 2
vec[i1:i2]
```

Output:

```
  Jan   Feb   Mar April 
    1     2     3     4
```

You would have to define `initial` and `last` in order to set the range.

Comment: This doesn't get the range, only those two values. I think OP is looking for something where `vec['Feb':'April']` would work, and include `Mar` in the output.